# How I can generate all combinations from RegEx (regular expression)?

Tags: python, regex, linux, bash, perl

For example, I have the following regular expression:

60[FP]LP[FP]XXXXXX

And now need all possible combinations, in this case:

60**F**LP**F**XXXXXX

60**F**LP**P**XXXXXX

60**P**LP**F**XXXXXX

60**P**LP**P**XXXXXX

Input RegEx is 12 characters long and consists of uppercase letters [A-Z] and numbers [0-9]

Comment: `ruby -e"strings = %w/60FLPFXXXXXX 60FLPPXXXXXX 60PLPFXXXXXX 60PLPPXXXXXX/;strings.each {|string| p /60([FLPF]{4})[A-Z0-9]{6}/.match(string)}"`

Comment: A regex could have infinitely many strings that will match. Think of any regex with `*` in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. With the tool rexgen (https://github.com/teeshop/rexgen) is it possible to generate all combinations from a given regular expression :)

```
$ rexgen 60[FP]LP[FP]XXXXXX
60FLPFXXXXXX
60PLPFXXXXXX
60FLPPXXXXXX
60PLPPXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression patterns defines a set of strings, so it's theoretically possible to use it to generate the list of strings in the set, but they aren't meant to do that. I'm not sure if someone's written a module to do that.

A glob, on the other hand, is designed to do exactly what you want. Could you use a glob instead?

```
say while glob('60{F,P}LP{F,P}XXXXXX');
```

Comment: A potentially infinite set of strings (e.g. `a*`) so in it's most general sense, the answer to the question is that it's not possible.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim, Not so. The fact that you don't have the time generate the matching set of every regex doesn't mean it's not possible. If it's possible to do with a glob, it's possible to do with a regex as well.

Comment: It's not possible, in the most general sense, to enumerate all strings that match any given glob pattern (e.g. `foo.*`) so my point still stands unless I've misunderstood your counter.

Comment: It is possible to do what the OP wants which is why I qualified my sentence with "in the most general sense".

Comment: I'm disagreeing with "*the answer to the question is that it's not possible*". You are wrong. It's possible to do what the OP wants, period. You can see it done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43159657/589924).  That fact that you can make infinite loops doesn't make "loops impossible in the general sense"!!!

Comment: for the question "Is it possible to write print all natural numbers to the console?" the answer is "YES". `i = 0; while (True) print(i);` theoretically prints all natural numbers. It will print (eventually) any natural number.
to contradict my statement "this code print all natural numbers" you must show that there is a natural number this code won't print. which you can't.
Therefore, it is possible to print all matches for a regex pattern.